# "Вайзивигизация" или contenteditable и ненавистный DIV

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

Когда делаешь элемент (в моё случае div) contenteditable="true"  при переводе строки вставляется `<div>`. Но если курсор стоял например в `<p>` то вставляется `<p></p>`, что меня больше утраивает. По примеру CREDITOR сделал, при клике, если поле пустое, то вставляется `<p><br></p>`. Но курсор все равно стоит на пустом месте и при переводе строки вставляет див. И вот как сделать чтобы теперь курсор попал в это `<p>`, чтобы дивы не штамповались?

Хотя вопрос поставлен не правильно. Как сделать чтобы при переводе строки вставлялись `<p>` вместо стандартных `<div>`?

Answer (score 1):

Разницу между `<div>` и `<p>` можно исправить стилями...

```
*[contenteditable] div, *[contenteditable] p {
    margin: 1em 0em 1em 0em;
}
```

Comment: Ну это совсем уж костыль. Меня все таки больше интересует javascript - решение. Но все равно спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `<p contenteditable></p>` вместо div...

Comment: К сожалению опять дивы.

Comment: Будет ещё хуже.

Answer (score 0):

А что если уже после редактирования заменить все тэги `<div>` на `<p>`?

Comment: Нет, надо сразу :))